# Display a Lemniscate (∞)

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

The infinity symbol is also called a lemniscate. Your program must draw a lemniscate with text via standard out (formatted with newline feeds) or graphically.

The infinity symbol (by my standards) must be continuous (that is, every non-whitespace character must be touching two other non-whitespace characters diagonally or orthogonally). It must also have two and no more than two gaps of enclosed whitespace (connectivity for whitespace is only orthogonal). Thus, the following output fails:

```
   ooo   ooo
 o    o o    o
o      o      o
 o    o o    o
   ooo   ooo
```

A correct version the above example might be

```
  oooo   oooo
 o    o o    o
o      o      o
 o    o o    o
  oooo   oooo
```

or

```
  ooo   ooo
 o   o o   o
o     o     o
 o   o o   o
  ooo   ooo
```

The size of the ∞ is unimportant. The orientation of the ∞ is unimportant. Symmetry is also unimportant. Graphical displays are accepted as well. Appropriate newline feeds are required in the output.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question so answers will be scored in bytes, with less bytes being better.

Comment: "Your program must draw a lemnescate with text". OK: `Print["∞"]`

Comment: @Notatree You can golf that to `Print@"∞"`, or `"∞"&` if a lambda function is acceptable. (I assume your language is Mathematica judging by the square brackets and upercase `Print`)

Comment: Gotta have a winning criterion, or people'll bury your question. ;) Are you asking for the shortest code possible?

Comment: Judging by the self-answer it should be code-golf.

Comment: @Phoenix Maybe you should switch to HTML, lol.

Comment: Why has this been closed as too broad?  I get that it lacks a winning criterion, which as JonathanAllen mentioned is likely intended to be code-golf, but closing as too broad without explanation baffles me.

Comment: @AdamMendenhall - Note for the future, there is a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) for preparing your questions for the main site; also it's good to be around for some time after you post a question (even if sandboxed) for the almost inevitable question or two regarding specifics.

Comment: I think this will come down to hardcoding a small string in all but the golfiest languages.

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks for the advice. I'm not really too keen on this question anymore. Still, the discourse is helpful and the answers are impressive to see.

Comment: How exactly are the conditions defined for graphical output?

Comment: @WheatWizard, it clearly *is* too broad. Just looking at the first couple of answers shows that it's about arguing that a given output falls under the umbrella provided by the spec rather than golfing an implementation of a narrowly defined spec. It's really a bunch of similar questions rather than one question.

Answer (score 12):

## Desmos, 22 bytes

```
r=\sqrt{\sin 2\theta }
```

[Try it here!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4v2mrzgzcp) Desmos is a graphing tool. This plots the polar equation:

[image: r = sqrt[sin 2 theta]]

which draws a lemniscate shape.

Comment: Where is "Desgos" and 4 bytes `s½2Θ`? :p

Comment: @JonathanAllan Believe it or not I was working a language to interface with desmos, I called it "sindesi". I started the project 2 ish years ago and haven't gotten back to it yet.

Answer (score 7):

## J, 8 bytes

```
3 5$' o'
```

Like Conor's, prints:

```
 o o 
o o o
 o o
```

`$` is J's shape operator, so we are creating a 3 x 5 grid, using the fill chacters  `o`.  When fill runs out, `$` repeats them cyclically by default.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/PzU5I1/BWMFURV0hX/3/fwA)

Comment: I _really_ like this one :D

Comment: Another approach for 11 bytes: `2":__,i.3 4`

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 4 bytes

```
∞&
```

I think this answer covers all the criteria

## Mathematica, 17 bytes

```
Graphics@Text@∞
```

@ovs's opinion is that the right answer is...

## Mathematica, 2 bytes

```
8&
```

and I agree!

Comment: Strictly speaking, I believe that's a snippet, not a program or function (but you can make it a function by putting `&` at the end).

Comment: Strictly speaking this is a very broad question...Why not? I'll edit!

Comment: I think an `8` matches all criteria as well. So `8&` for 2 bytes

Comment: @ovs I agree! posted!

Comment: Neither single character answers fit the criteria that "every non-whitespace character must be touching [at least] two other non-whitespace characters diagonally or orthogonally"

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica - 49 bytes

```
ParametricPlot[{ReIm[Sin[t+I Sin[t]]]},{t,0,2Pi}]
```

Result:

[image: Output]

Comment: Is this acceptable? To answer your own challenge?

Comment: Ps: The downvote was not me.

Comment: [Can I compete in my own challenge?](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1590/29325)

Comment: Can you give a screenshot of the output?

Comment: You can golf this down a bit, using `@` and the fact you don't need a list for the first parameter: `ReIm@Sin[t+I Sin@t]~ParametricPlot~{t,0,2Pi}` for 44 bytes.

Comment: @Phoenix added an image of the result.

Answer (score 2):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 13 bytes

```
/z/ o o
/zozz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K85JLM5ILf7/X79KXyFfIZ9Lvyq/qur/fwA) Outputs:

```
 o o
o o o
 o o
```

I think this is the smallest valid "lemniscate" allowed by the rules.

Comment: I always try to improve my content, so please, do try and leave a comment with your downvote.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```python
print"o o\nooo\n"*3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v6AoM69EKV8hPyYvPx9IKGkZ//8PAA)

This prints:

```python
o o
ooo
o o
ooo
o o
ooo
```

It may not look like a lemnescate but it has two enclosed spaces (marked with `x`)

```python
o o
ooo
oxo
ooo
oxo
ooo
```

And every `o` is connected to at least two other `o`s.  Thus despite not looking anything like what it is supposed to this fulfills the bare-minimum requirements.

Comment: heh, I was just going to say o o, ooo :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan It looks like you pointing out an error helped me *save* a byte.  So double thanks for that. :)

Comment: I think you can remove one of the o's: `"o o\noo\n"`

Comment: @xnor You can not, the top right `o` is only touching one other `o` in that case.

Comment: I don't understand how you can ask why the question was voted "Too Broad" and also post this answer. The fact that you think you can argue that this meets the spec is exhibit A. And if this is valid, then surely `8` is a valid answer in CJam, GolfScript, etc.?

Comment: you can golf this down to 10 bytes: `print"∞"`

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't see what you are saying.  The original post pretty clearly lays out specific requirements for answers, and this fits those requirements.  Just because this looks like an `8` does not mean that this is the same as printing an `8`.  An `8` on its own meets *none* of the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
8RKḊs5Y
```

As a full program prints:

```
 2 3 
4 5 6
 7 8
```

Which seems to adhere to the specification.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98iyPvhjq5i08j///8DAA)**

#### How?

```
8RKḊs5Y - Main link: no arguments
8R      - range of 8 -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
  K     - join with spaces -> [1,' ',2,' ',3,' ',4,' ',5,' ',6,' ',7,' ',8]
   Ḋ    - dequeue -> [' ',2,' ',3,' ',4,' ',5,' ',6,' ',7,' ',8]
    s5  - split into chunks of length 5 -> [[' ',2,' ',3,' '],[4,' ',5,' ',6],[' ',7,' ',8]]
      Y - join with newlines -> [' ',2,' ',3,' ',`\n`,4,' ',5,' ',6,'\n',' ',7,' ',8]
        - implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes (ASCII-art version)

```
ＧＨX²o‖Ｂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARwA4/9jaGFyY29hbP//77yn77yoWMKyb@KAlu@8ov//)

The first part (`ＧＨX²o`) prints a hollow polygon of size 2 in the `X` direction using the `o` char as border, that results in this:

```
 o 
o o
 o
```

Then I only have to reflect the canvas horizontally (skipping the middle column), to get this:

```
 o o
o o o
 o o
```

Link to the [verbose version](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8gP6cyPT/PIz8nJ79cwypCR8FIR0EpX0nTmisoNS0nNbnEqbSkJLUoLadSQ9P6////umX/dYtzAA).

Comment: 6 bytes: `↙oo‖ＢT`.

Comment: @Neil whawhawhat??? You can use complex directions with `ReflectButterfly`??

Comment: You can use any sequence of directions. It just happens that `:T` expands to `:Right, :Down, :Left` which is exactly what's needed to reflect the two `o`s to give the hexagon.

Comment: In fact you're using the same trick with your `PolygonHollow` - `:X` expands to the four diagonals, so `PolygonHollow` just draws a diamond shape.

Comment: The single character answer does not fit the criteria that "every non-whitespace character must be touching [at least] two other non-whitespace characters diagonally or orthogonally"

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 bytes

```
o↘ooo‖Ｂ¬←
```

Draws the actual last example. 10-byte version that takes a size parameter as input:

```
Ｇ→↘↘Ｎo‖Ｂ¬←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z8gP6cyPT9PwyooMz2jREfByiW/PA8L2zOvoLTErzQ3KbVIQ1NHQSlfSdOaKyg1LSc1ucSptKQktSgtp1LD6tAaoDaf1LQSTev//43@65b91y3OAQA) Link is to verbose version of code.

Answer (score 0):

**C , 55 bytes**

```
i;f(){while(i++<18)putchar(i%6?(i/6+i)%2?32:'o':'\n');}
```

outputs

[image: Lemniscate]